# Uploading a file in Asp.Net - Asynchronous Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

So I'm net to ASP.net MVC, but not new to C#. I've linked in my project with the data source, and it's created all of my Create Read Update Delete methods and views. Great. Now I need to customize some things.

First thing, I need to upload a .csv file, this is what will populate one of our models, as a stopgap while we migrate from an old pen-and-paper system.

Here's postback method that get's called when the submit button gets pressed:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "callout_id_pk,start_timestamp,drivers_license_needed,med_training_needed,worksite_code_fk,shift_notes,status,job_class_code_fk,worksite_name,job_class_name,gender_req")] Callout callout)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("THIS LINE OF CODE RAN?");
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Callouts.Add(callout);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }


            foreach (string upload in Request.Files)
            {
                if (Request.Files[upload].ContentLength == 0) continue;
                string pathToSave = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/UploadedFiles");
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[upload].FileName);
                Request.Files[upload].SaveAs(Path.Combine(pathToSave, filename));
            }

            ViewBag.worksite_code_fk = new SelectList(db.Worksites, "worksite_code_pk", "worksite_name", callout.worksite_code_fk);
            return View(callout);
        }
```

And here's the view, with the non-pertinent controls removed for readability.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Callouts", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype="multipart/form-data"})) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


        <!--@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })-->

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="file" name="FileUpload1" /><br />
        </div>

        <!-- other form controls here -->

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
}
```

Now, for some reason in the postback, Request.Files is not seeing any files posted back. What am I missing here? Note that for now, I'm just trying to save the file to disk. But in the end, the file will be read and used to populate the model.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to be really dumb. My file upload logic was BELOW a chunk of code that called 'return' if ModelState.IsValid()...